# Divs are not resizing properly on window resize

Tags: css

I'm making a website which has three divs. I'm trying to make them fit properly in the wrapper but when I resize the window, the green box goes under the other two if the window gets small. If i resize the window, it seems like the divs are not resizing properly. Here is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/nq5qwwnc/.

Here is the wrappe

```
`       
    width: 70vw;
    height: 80vh;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    left: 50%;
    border: 2px solid black`
```

What I'm trying to do is keep them all next to each other even when the window resizes.

Comment: I've only managed to reproduce said bug when the viewport width is below ~290px. Do you reasonably expect any of your users to have a screen this small? You could try adding `box-sizing: border-box` to make that breakpoint even smaller, but the last div still jumps into a new line at ~120px width.

Comment: No, but it seems like the spacing is off too. When I resize the window, the space between the red and blue boxes stay the same while the space between the blue and green one changes and most of the time these two spaces are different widths.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to do a layout like this and want responsiveness, I suggest you to check out [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), it makes doing responsive layouts much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking into [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  They provide a very easy way to arrange elements into rows or columns in a responsive way.

In your example, for instance:

```
#mainWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.firstBox, .thirdBox {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.secondBox {
  flex: 0 0 55%;
}
```

This tells the first and third box to be 20% in width, and the second box 55% in width.  The `0 0` part determines whether the boxes dynamically grow to fit the remaining space in the main wrapper; I've set them to not grow in this case.

Try seeing if you can get this working in your js fiddle!